# How to find audio files in the app directory in flutter using on_audio_query

Tags: android, flutter

I am making an app that allows users to download songs and store them in the app directory this is the directory `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.zylae/files`. But whenever I add the 'path' thingy to the 'querySongs' thingy, I don't get any songs at all.

Here the code, I kinda edited the one from the on_audio_query page

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:on_audio_query/on_audio_query.dart';

class AudioQ extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioQ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AudioQState createState() => _AudioQState();
}

class _AudioQState extends State<AudioQ> {
  // Main method.
  final OnAudioQuery _audioQuery = OnAudioQuery();

  // Indicate if application has permission to the library.
  bool _hasPermission = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // (Optinal) Set logging level. By default will be set to 'WARN'.
    //
    // Log will appear on:
    //  * XCode: Debug Console
    //  * VsCode: Debug Console
    //  * Android Studio: Debug and Logcat Console
    LogConfig logConfig = LogConfig(logType: LogType.DEBUG);
    _audioQuery.setLogConfig(logConfig);

    // Check and request for permission.
    checkAndRequestPermissions();
  }

  checkAndRequestPermissions({bool retry = false}) async {
    // The param 'retryRequest' is false, by default.
    _hasPermission = await _audioQuery.checkAndRequest(
      retryRequest: retry,
    );

    // Only call update the UI if application has all required permissions.
    _hasPermission ? setState(() {}) : null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // _audioQuery.querySongs();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("OnAudioQueryExample"),
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: !_hasPermission
            ? noAccessToLibraryWidget()
            : FutureBuilder<List<SongModel>>(
                // Default values:
                future: _audioQuery.querySongs(
                  sortType: null,
                  orderType: OrderType.ASC_OR_SMALLER,
                  uriType: UriType.EXTERNAL,
                  ignoreCase: true,
                  path: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.zylae/files/downloads',
                ),
                builder: (context, item) {
                  // Display error, if any.
                  if (item.hasError) {
                    return Text(item.error.toString());
                  }

                  // Waiting content.
                  if (item.data == null) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }

                  // 'Library' is empty.
                  if (item.data!.isEmpty) return const Text("Nothing found!");

                  // You can use [item.data!] direct or you can create a:
                  // List<SongModel> songs = item.data!;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: item.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(item.data![index].title),
                        subtitle: Text(item.data![index].artist ?? "No Artist"),
                        trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_rounded),
                        // This Widget will query/load image.
                        // You can use/create your own widget/method using [queryArtwork].
                        leading: QueryArtworkWidget(
                          controller: _audioQuery,
                          id: item.data![index].id,
                          type: ArtworkType.AUDIO,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget noAccessToLibraryWidget() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const Text("Application doesn't have access to the library"),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => checkAndRequestPermissions(retry: true),
            child: const Text("Allow"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried removing the first '/', but it did not work

Comment: You can simply list the content of that directory yourself. Further it is unclear who you are querying. And why do you think you need which permission?

Comment: The permission was to check if I have permission to view and edit files on the phone. And I want to query the songs in the app directory, i.e **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.zylae/files** , but it seems like it can not get them. Any suggestions ?? I can not list the content of the directory because it depends on what the user downloads

Comment: You can of course list that directory. Its one of your app's private directories. It does only depend on if there are files in .../files directory. No permission needed. You can view and edit them as much as you want.

Comment: I just tried it, it still shows nothing

Comment: Then the directory was empty.

Comment: `...files/downloads` Who created that directory there? And how? And who placed files there? How?

Comment: Try file.exists() and file.canRead() before you try to list.

Comment: Okay so when I download a song through the app, it checks if this folder exists `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.zylae/files/downloads` , if it doesnt it creates it, if it does, it saves the mp3 file there. But after I download a song, it doesn't show in my library with onAudioQuery, but I see it on the phones explorer

Comment: You realise that you placed the file in a private directory of your app? Other apps, not even file managers, have no access.

Comment: `it doesn't show in my library ` We have no idea what you mean with your library.

Comment: Yh, I wanted the songs to be in the private folder to make sure they are not shared. But onAudio query doesn't seem to find them.

Comment: Sorry, I meant  that I have a tab called library, where all the downloaded songs should be, but they dont show upon downloading. And I know they are downloaded because I see the songs in the private folder, with ZArchiver.